# how do I set up html with text and images for flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app, which looks like:

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=["GET","POST"])
def predict():    
    if request.method == "POST":        
        if request.files:
            raw_data = request.files['image'].read()         
            finalNumpyArray=np.array(json.loads(raw_data), dtype = 'uint8')
            processed_image = preprocess_image(finalNumpyArray)
            processed_image1 = preprocess_image1(finalNumpyArray)    
            prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()
            f1 = plt.imshow(processed_image1, interpolation='none')
            f1.show()

            response = {
                'prediction': {
                    'Center': prediction[0][0],
                    'Donut': prediction[0][1],
                    'Edge-Loc': prediction[0][2],
                    'Edge-Ring': prediction[0][3],
                    'Loc': prediction[0][4],
                    'Random': prediction[0][5],
                    'Scratch': prediction[0][6],
                    'None': prediction[0][7],
                }
            }


            return jsonify(response)
    return render_template("predict.html")
```

The first predict page shows the "predict.html" page, where you can upload an image to get it predicted by the model I have loaded in the app. Once uploaded, the second page comes up, with the jsonify(response).

I'd like to change the jsonify(response) to an html that has a nice readout for the "response" variable, and that also shows the f1 figure, plt.imshow(...). The figure looks like this.

[plt.imshow(...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQaxI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `render_template` to render a [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) template.

Have a look at the Flask documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates).

In essence you would replace your `return jsonify(response)` with something like this:

```
return render_template('your_template.html', prediction=response['prediction'])
```

Now your Jinja2 template would have the prediction dictionary available in the `prediction` template variable.

For the `f1` image you would need to save this first to disk somehow (e.g. using `plt.imsave()`, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html)) and then pass the path to the file also to the `render_template` call so that you can use it in an `<img />` tag in your template.